# Distribute numbers as close to possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This seems to be a 2 step problem I'm trying to solve.

Let's say we have N records, and we are trying to distribute as evenly as possible into K groups.

The second problem - each group in K can only accept an M amount of records.

For example, if we have 5 records, and 3 groups, then we would distribute 2 into Group K1, 2 into Group K2 and 1 record into Group K3. However, if say in group 1, it only accepts at most 1 record. Then the arrangement would need to be 1 into Group K1, 2 into Group K2, and 2 into Group K3.

I'm not necessary after the solution but what algorithm I might need to use to solve this? Apparently for the distribution, I need to use the Greedy algorithm? But for the second step, this seems to be a bit more complicated

Edit:
The example I'm looking at is:
   `Number of records: 23
    Groups: 10 
    Max records for each group
    G1 = 4
    G2 = 1
    G3 = 0
    G4 = 5 
    G5 = 0
    G6 = 0
    G7 = 2
    G8 = 4
    G9 = 2
    G10 = 2`

Answer (score 0):

if N=12 and K=3 then in normal situation,you just split it V=12/3=4 for each group. but since you have M limitation, and for example K3 can only accept 1 then the distribution can be 6-5-1 which is not evenly distributed.

So i guess you need to sort K based on the M limitation, so for the example above the groups order become K3-K1-K2.

then if the distributed value V is bigger than the accepted amount M for that group, you need to take the remainder and distribute it again to the remaining group (K3=1, then 4-1=3 must be distributed to K1 and K2).

the implementation might be complicated, i hope you can find more simple solution for this

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need to separate all groups which allows a fixed number of values first and then equally distribute records among remaining groups. Let's take an example, let's say we have 15 records which needs to be distributed among 5 groups (G1, G2, G3, G4 and G5). Also let's assume that G2 and G4 allows max records of 2 and 4 respectively. Now algorithm should go like this:

1. Get average(ceiling integer) of records based on number of groups (In this example we'll get 3).
2. Add all max allowed records which are smaller than our average (In this example it's G2 only who's max limit(i.e. 2) is less than our average hence the number comes as 2).
3. Now subtract our number from step 2 from total records and also subtract the number of groups involved in step 2 from total groups. (remaining total records: 13, remaining total groups 4).
4. Get the new average(ceiling integer) using remaining records and groups. (New average 4).
5. Get average (Integer) (i.e. 3) and allot equal number of records to remaining groups - 1.
6. Get Mod (i.e. 1) and allot that number to the last group.

Now what we finally will have here:
G1(No limit):          **4**
G2(Limit 2):           **2**
G3(No limit):          **4**
G4(Limit 4):           **4**
G5(No limit):          **1**

Let me know if you think that this algo might fail for some scenarios.

Formula to get ceiling integer average
floor((@total_records + @total_groups-1) / @total_groups)

Comment: Still trying to understand this but just for clarification, each group will always have a max amount of records allowed

Comment: The example I'm looking at is:
Number of records: 23
Groups: 10 
Max records for each group
G1 = 4 
G2 = 1
G3 = 0
G4 = 5 
G5 = 0
G6 = 0 
G7 = 2
G8 = 4
G9 = 2
G10 = 2

Comment: Can you explain how you get 4 as an average in your first point?

Comment: @user172839 I made some corrections, thanks for pointing them out, And I think this same algo would work even if all groups had limits defined on them. Let me know if it does/doesn't work for you.

Comment: There's a major issue that I came across whilst trying to use this method the other day. When you get to the last group,  you may have more records available than the max allotment for that group, in which case you need to allocate the remaining to the other groups if they weren't filled to the maximum capacity or else discard the lot if there's no more capacity in any groups.